# how to put methods in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models, `Client` and `PaymentOptions`.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=False)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, unique=False)

class ClientPaymentOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=False, choices=CARD_TYPE)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=False, choices=CLIENT_PAYMENT_OPTION)
    percent = models.FloatField(max_length=10, null=True, unique=False)
    fixamount = models.FloatField(max_length=20, null=True, unique=False)
    itemcharged = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, unique=False)
```

in my admin.py I have this :

```
admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #display list
    list_display = ('name','contact','address')
    #display fields
    fields = ('name','contact','address')
    pass
admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)

class PaymentOptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'action', 'percent', 'fixamount', 'itemcharged', 'client')
    fields = ('name', 'action','percent', 'fixamount', 'itemcharged', 'client')
admin.site.register(ClientPaymentOption, ClientPaymentOptionAdmin)
```

is it possible that whenever I create a new `Client` in `django admin` it will also automatically create it's `ClientPaymentOption`?

I try to do this in my admin.py:

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #display list
    list_display = ('name','b_type','banner','logo',
                    'contact','address','account_type',
                    'status','currency','color','user',
                    )
    #display fields
    fields = ('name','b_type','banner','logo','contact',
              'address','account_type','status',
              'currency','color','user',
              )
    pass
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        ClientPaymentOption.objects.create(name='MasterCard',action='% Charged', client=obj.id, percent=0.10)
        ClientPaymentOption.objects.create(name='Visa', action='% Charged',client=obj.id, percent=0.10)
```

but i got this error:

```
ValueError at /admin/client_app/client/add/
Cannot assign None: "ClientPaymentOption.client" does not allow null values.
```

when I try to `print` the parameters, i have noticed that the Client still not saved...

```
print obj.id
None
```

do anyone have an idea or suggestion about my case?

thanks in advance ...

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-syncdb

`post_syncdb` is exactly what you're looking for. It's the same pattern the docs use to describe the automatic creation of a `UserProfile` every time a `User` is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the parent's method before attempting to create the new objects.